# Removing the <br /> tags from an XML string in PHP

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, strip-tags

I have an upload form that permits user submitted XML files, which are then inserted into WordPress as the contents of a new post. This is working fine, however the XML string has a `</br>` tag after every line that I would like to remove. I looked at `strip_tags` but there are far too many allowed tags to use that.

How can I remove these `br` elements from the string when importing the contents?

```
function slicer_profile_submit()
{
    // if the submit button is clicked, submit
    if (isset($_POST['slicer-profile-submitted']))
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['slicer-profile']['tmp_name']) or die("Error: Cannot upload file. Please contact the administrator.");
        $contents = '<textarea rows="12">' . $xml->asXML() . '</textarea>';

        // sanitize form values
        $profile_author = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["slicer-profile-author"] );
        $profile_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["slicer-profile-name"] );
        $profile_model = $_POST["slicer-profile-model"];
        $profile_software = $_POST["slicer-profile-software"];

        // Create post object
        $slicer_profile = array(
            'post_title'    => $profile_name,
            'post_content'  => $contents,
            'post_type' => 'slicer_profiles',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'meta_input' => array(
                'slicer_profile_author' => $profile_author
            )
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $slicer_profile );
    }
}
```

The results:

[image]

Comment: [str_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) them maybe? Or make sure they don't show up in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` to remove unwanted characters or strings from your response.

It will clear the strings you have mentioned in the function and will return the output

```
$properresponse = preg_replace('/&nbsp;|<br \/>/i', '', $your_string);
```

Comment: I tried adding this after the $contents= line to remove them before inserting the contents the new post. It seems they are still showing afterwards though, where I am wondering if perhaps Wordpress adds these.

I tried using it in the post template as well, running it against the_content() before displaying it, but they still appear for some reason.

   <?php $content = preg_replace('/&nbsp;|<br \/>/i', '', the_content()); ?>
   <?php echo $content; ?>

Comment: @AidanKnight Did you try adding this code `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` in your functions.php file
Reference Link - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: My site uses that on almost all other pages, I only need to disable it on this one specific post type. Can this be used from within my plugin for just that or is it only in functions.php?

Comment: Well I tested it and that fixed it so I guess I will have to figure out some way to do it just for my custom post type. Thank you!

Comment: @AidanKnight Welcome! I'm happy it helps you to resolve your problem!